# Font Awesome in JavaFX: How to set ALL of the colors of an icon (separately)

Tags: java, text, colors, javafx, font-awesome

I have a Font Awesome icon represented as a Text object: `Text icon = GlyphsDude.createIcon(FontAwesomeIcon.EXCLAMATION_TRIANGLE)`.

In the icon for this example, the exclamation triangle, there are two colors. The black body of the triangle and the white exclamation mark.

I have figured out how to change the color of the black body by doing `icon.setId("my-icon");`

And then use the following CSS file (which of course is set to the stylesheet of my java class):

```
#my-icon {
 -fx-fill: green;
}
```

This will change the color of the black triangle body to green. But how do I change the color of the exclamation mark? As of now the exclamation mark will be the same color as the background (or well to be exact, the exclamation mark is just a hole in the triangle that shows the layer beneath the triangle), and you can't set a background color for a Text object. I could set the background color of whatever is containing the icon, but that would not only color the exclamation mark but everything else in the container.

`-fx-stroke` is the closest I've gotten so far. But that will only change the border of the exclamation mark. It also adds an unwanted effect in coloring the border of the triangle as well.

I'm guessing there must be an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting "-fx-background-color"?

Comment: Yup. As explained in the question, you can not set the background color of a Text object. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think you can't change the exclamation mark colour simply because it doesn't exist. I mean, the icon is a triangle with a hole, and that hole has the shape of an exclamation mark. Simple test: an app with a pane, inside the pane put the icon. Now, if you change the pane -fx-background-color you'll see the exclamation mark has the same colour as that background.